# a woman who bears many children

Tags: vocabulary

How does the West take the word 'prolific' for a woman?

If a lady has given birth to many children, she is physically that strong, I mean, then would she like to be called 'a prolific woman'?

1. Prolific
2. Fertile
3. Children-bearing
4. Or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "prolific" refers to someone who has a large output of anything. A "prolific writer" is a writer who has written many books. A "prolific shoemaker" is one who has made many shoes. Etc. So a "prolific woman" COULD be a woman who has had many children. But it could also mean a woman who has produced a lot of ... anything. If in context you were talking about how many children each person had had, and then you said, "And Sally Jones has been absolutely prolific", in context we would presumably understand that to mean prolific at producing children. But if you were talking about how many books each other had written, and then said that Sally Jones was prolific, a reader would understand that to mean that she is a writer who has written many books.

If you want to introduce the idea that a particular woman has had many children, most fluent English speakers would say, "Sally Jones has had many children." You COULD say "Sally Jones is very fertile", but, (a) This would be ambiguous. To you mean that she has had many children? Or that she is very capable of having children but may or may not have had any yet? (b) It's fairly obscure way to express the idea. A doctor or geneticist might say that, but few English speakers would use the word "fertile" with that meaning in casual conversation or writing.

Answer (score 3):

"Fertile" would describe what you mean the most clearly, but beware of how you use it.

Generally, women like to be evaluated by their skills and character, not their child-bearing ability. Having children is a personal choice, not a trait, and it's not other people's place to approve or disapprove. So regardless of the specific words, talking about how many children someone has in a positive rather than neutral way has potential to offend.

If you're simply observing, stick to facts only: "She has a lot of children." If you must judge, make it explicit: "She has a lot of children, [and I think that's good because ______________]/[which shows that she ______________]." This shows that it's *your* opinion rather than something you assume is *everyone's* opinion.

Comment: We might use _prolific_ to describe a woman in history, but it wouldn't be seen as particularly complimentary to a living woman.

Comment: @KateBunting On that note, I suppose we could describe a woman as prolific in her profession or field, even a living one. That's a little out of scope though.

Comment: You mean something like 'a prolific author'? I was only thinking of the sense 'producing many children'.

Comment: "Generally, women like to be evaluated by their skills and character, not their child-bearing ability." Yeah, there are words I can think of, but you wouldn't actually use them outside of specific contexts because of how insulting they could be seen as.

Comment: "This shows that it's your opinion rather than something that is everyone's opinion." That would be true of almost any judgement. People disagree about value judgements all the time. Including, by the way, the one you just made. Some would say, "No, that's not my opinion, that's a universal truth, and if you don't agree, you are simply wrong." Of course you could reply that it is not. I always get a laugh when someone says or implies, "this is something that everyone agrees with", when the truth is "that I and all my friends agree with".

Answer (score 1):

### Broodmare.

One (pretty insulting) word for a woman who has had a large number of children is "broodmare", which is the word for a female horse that is being kept for breeding.

It wouldn't be the sort of thing you called someone else to their face unless you wanted to insult them, though looking online I cam see at least one instance of a feminist accusing people who promote natalist policies as "treating women like broodmares".